# Why does the maximum call stack size differ from sample to sample?

Tags: javascript, callstack

If I try

```
var count = 0

function recurse() {
  count++
  recurse()
}

try {
  recurse()
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message, count)
}
```

the result is `Maximum call stack size exceeded 15662`, but if I try

```
var count = 0

function recurse() {
  count++
  ( new Function( recurse.toString().split('\n').splice(1, 2).join('\n') ) )()
}

try {
  recurse()
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message, count)
}
```

then the result is `Maximum call stack size exceeded 8862`.

Why are the numbers different?

Comment: Because in first scenario the size of each recursive call is smaller. the quotient (stack size / function call size on stack ) is bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in first scenario the size of each recursive function call's machine code is smaller. the quotient (stack size / function call size on stack ) is bigger.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ah, according to http://2ality.com/2014/04/call-stack-size.html,

> the number of recursive calls you can make depends on two quantities: the size of the stack and the size of the stack frame (holding parameters and local variables).

Answer (score 0):

Because of stack belong not exclusively to your program.

For example, when your program is running, can be handled asynchronous interrupt, or your task can be suspended by scheduler and CPU switched to another task. If so, current context (registers, PSW) of your task saved in the stack, and resumed, when you got control back.

As result: stack consumption can be vary, and all values below stack pointer (SP) are undefined. And if you save something below SP, not fact, you will read same.